# Windows Script Host file size limit \ Cannot retrieve referenced URL exception

Tags: javascript, wsh

So I'm trying to use JSTest.Net https://github.com/cbaxter/JSTest.NET and it uses Windows Script Host to attach scripts.

I'm trying to append OpenLayers.js which is 958 KB when compressed and 2590 KB when uncompressed. I have encountered this issue where it says - Cannot retrieve the referenced URL. I think (and also the developer pointed me out to the same thing) it is the file size that is causing the problem.

I also came across this question where a user pointed out the same issue but in a different context ([Cannot retrieve referenced URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822944/cannot-retrieve-referenced-url))
but no work around was suggested.

Did anyone encounter the same problem, if so were you able to find a solution for that?

Comment: Why don't you just wait for the issue you submitted (https://github.com/cbaxter/JSTest.NET/issues/7)  to be taken care of? It looks like the developer is going to work on it. And the problem seems to be with Windows Script Host anyway.

Comment: Well that is always a choice, but it never hurts to ask in general if anyone has come up with an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

The SO question you linked and [the forum link in it](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1345627) shows the problem to be an undocumented 512KB size limit in importing scripts with WSH.

Also, the accepted answer for that SO question implies you might want to make sure it's not running as admin.

Make sure your Visual Studio (or whatever you're running JSTest.NET from) isn't running with administrator privileges and see if that helps.