# How can I split the file and output it with Webpack? This is to avoid the WSH capacity limit

Tags: webpack, jscript, wsh

I'm not native English, so I'm sorry if it feels difficult to read.

I am creating a library.
https://github.com/standard-software/partsjs/tree/v9.2.0

I'm building with Webpack and it's comfortable to use.

There is one problem.
Parts.js used to support WSH, but the file size has increased and it has exceeded 512KB.

It's not a problem to use a modern project with a file of that size, but only the operation in the WSH environment is a problem.
There seems to be a limit that WSH file links can only accept 512KB.

[Windows Script Host file size limit \ Cannot retrieve referenced URL exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944347/windows-script-host-file-size-limit-cannot-retrieve-referenced-url-exception)

[Cannot retrieve referenced URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822944/cannot-retrieve-referenced-url)

VBScript maximum script size? - VBScript - Tek-Tips
https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1345627

Windows Script Host: Cannot retrieve referenced URL (512KB File Size) · Issue #7 · cbaxter/JSTest.NET
https://github.com/cbaxter/JSTest.NET/issues/7

It's an incredible limitation, but I was trying to give up on the WSH environment because the WSH environment is so old that it can't be helped. What can I do with the Webpack build settings?

Is the question.

I will write my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the settings in Webpack.config.js.

Use webpack.optimize.AggressiveSplittingPlugin.

The specific code is here
https://github.com/standard-software/partsjs/tree/v10.0.0/config

A normal build is described like this.

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: ['./build/babel_webpack/babel/index.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'parts.js',
    path: __dirname + '/../build/babel_webpack/webpack/',
    library: 'parts',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    globalObject: 'this',
  },
};
```

You will have only one file called parts.js.

Only build for WSH is made like this.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: ['./build/babel_webpack/babel/index.js'],
  output: {
    filename: 'parts.js',
    path: __dirname + '/../build/babel_webpack/webpack_forWsh/',
    library: 'parts',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    globalObject: 'this',
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveSplittingPlugin({
      minSize: 1000,
      maxSize: 200000,
    }),
  ],
};
```

This will split the file into 200KB and create multiple files.

```
1.parts.js
2.parts.js
parts.js
```

When linking this to a WSH JScript file

```
<script language = "JavaScript" src = "xxx / 2.parts.js"> </ script>
<script language = "JavaScript" src = "xxx / 1.parts.js"> </ script>
<script language = "JavaScript" src = "xxx / parts.js"> </ script>
```

If you write it like this, it will work properly.

I didn't know how to do this, so I made a detour a lot.

Originally it was 512KB or less
https://github.com/standard-software/partsjs/blob/v7.6.0/config/

Only the test code exceeded 512KB, so I had no choice but to disguise require
https://github.com/standard-software/partsjs/blob/v8.0.0/config/

ver9.0.0 after The main body code was also 512KB over, so I gave up support.

webpack.config.js I finally figured out how to use webpack.optimize.AggressiveSplittingPlugin
https://github.com/standard-software/partsjs/tree/v10.0.0/config

I am very grateful that Webpack can do this as well.
I've considered other bundle tools, but choosing Webpack was a great help.

If you still want to fight in WSH projects, you can make projects over 512KB work properly with build settings.

Whether it's a huge library or a huge application in a babel / webpack environment, there is webpack.optimize.AggressiveSplittingPlugin, so you can still fight well.

I hope you can refer to the build method.